# php usort сортировка по алфавиту

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой код

```
    usort($clinic, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['DISTANCE'] == $b['DISTANCE']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['DISTANCE'] < $b['DISTANCE']) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

он сортирует массив по возрастанию.

Вопрос как сделать сортировку по алфавиту имен, на основе такоже кода ?
Что-то вроде этого, но он работает не верно.

```
        usort($clinic, function($a, $b){                  
        return ($a['NAME'] < $b['NAME']);
        });
```

Не могу понять логику usort, может объяснит кто или пример скажет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usort` работает аналогично `sort` за одной разницей, что функцию сравнения задаёт пользователь.
У вас уже есть рабочий код (первый пример). Почему в него вместо "DISTANCE" не подставить "NAME"?

Callback функции сортировок должны возвращать 3 значения:

- 0 - первое значение равно второму
- 1 - первое значение больше второго
- -1 - первое значение меньше второго

В вашем втором примере возвращается boolean значение, который к integer приводится как:

- true - 1
- false - 0

Другими словами, ваша функция вернёт:

- 1 - первое значение меньше второго
- 0 - первое значение больше или равно второму

Поэтому, у вас и неправильная сортировка.

Изменив ваш же код, получаем:

```
usort($clinic, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['NAME'] == $b['NAME']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['NAME'] < $b['NAME']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Если я не совсем правильно понял суть, поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да так работает, я и сам проверял до этого, разобрался, проблема была в том что в один php файл запихнули несколько функций которые сортируют один список, поэтому и не одна сортировка не работала верно, спасибо большое)

Comment: всем спасибо большое, оказывается я уже пробовал правильный вариант, но не заметил что один и тотже массив фильтруется несколькими функциями, эх уж эти быдлокодеры..

Поэтому и удивился, почему не работает аналогичный вариант только с массивом NAME вместо RATE

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать так: Стандартными  функциями php:

```
$strings = array('/root/mandy/c.pdf', '/root/mandy/a.pdf', '/root/mandy/b.pdf');
sort($strings);
print_r($strings);
```

У меня так работает нормально.

Comment: это понятно, но дело в том что это ассоциативный массив, и в нем много других массивов, например код выше который сортирует по расстанию он работает, нужно что - то наподобие только для строк

Comment: @S1lllver тогда дайте правильный вопрос, надо посмотреть пример массива

Comment: сейчас поправлю

Comment: всем спасибо, разобрался